# Why is my second SKView not being updated?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I placed two SKViews in my storyboard and hooked them up via outlets. They are both rendering the correct content, and updating their FPS displays. I can change their cameras position and again both are rendering correctly.

But the `update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)` method of their SKScene is only being called in the first SKView. If I remove the outlet of the first SKView then the second SKView starts getting its update method called.

Is it not allowed to have more than one SKView in a UIViewController at the same time? Or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update method is part of SKScene and you can only have one active SKScene at any one time.